# SvnLook with unicode Ouptut

Tags: svn, character-encoding, visualsvn-server, svnlook

On Windows Vista, with Subversion 1.6.12 setup throught VisualSvn Server 2.1.3, I have the following output

```
Commentaires AccentuÚs.
```

Instead of

```
Commentaires Accentués.
```

with the command (in a dos or powershell console in admin mode)

```
svnlook log "D:\MyRepo"
```

I've tried with other subversion binaries distribution (silksvn) and always the same problem !
How to tell svnlook on windows to output in Unicode or at least current windows encoding ?

*Note :* I don't think this question is a duplicate of ["svnlook changed" encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808859/svnlook-changed-encoding) : I'm on windows and it's not a problem related to Hooks.

Thanks...

Comment: Total shot in the dark, but try `chcp 1252` and `chcp 65000` before calling svnlook, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it has no effects.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Sebastian Schumann : No, as far as I remember, I never found a solution. I don't use subversion anymore.